# Moderator inbox messages are not dismissed from chat / mobile notifications

Tags: bug, global-inbox, top-bar

When I read a moderator inbox item, like this one:

[image]

… it still shows as an unread inbox item in chat and the mobile view:

[image]

I read the question, so it should be marked as such in the "old style" inbox.

Comment: So are all notifications, see the dupe :-)